# Performance impact of using Workflow Foundation

Tags: performance, workflow, workflow-foundation

I realize this is a quite general question, but I am wondering about the performance impact of implementing business logic with WF contra imperative code in fairly large enterprise system. I would like to hear others experiences in this regard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check [Performance Characteristics of Windows Workflow Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973808.aspx) for key performance considerations and modeling guidelines that are important when developing applications on top of the Windows Workflow Foundation.

However I would suggest to wait for the WF 4.0 announcement at PDC (end of October) since [they are promising](http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/9/B/59B74A2A-245D-4304-802E-E0A0800FACD3/Dublin__NET_4_overview.docx)

> **Significant improvements in
>   performance and scalability** (Ten-fold
>   improvement in performance)

---

EDIT (after PDC, 11Nov08):

OK, not much revealed about performance at PDC, although Kenny Wolf [said in his talk](http://channel9.msdn.com/pdc2008/TL17/) that there are 10-100X performance improvements from execution speed to persistence sizes.

Moreover, Rick Garibay posted some post-talk discussions with Kenny Wolf [here](http://rickgaribay.net/archive/2008/10/28/wf-4.0-big-changes-ahead.aspx). I am copying a relevant passage:

> My first question was around the
>   impetus for such a major overhaul.
>   Kenny shared that they focused very,
>   very deeply on key customer requests
>   and opportunities based on earlier
>   versions of the framework. There were
>   3 feature types that resonated most.
>   First, is delivering a truly
>   model-based framework that allows
>   every aspect of the WF to be
>   represented declaratively. Second, was
>   being able to truly participate in the
>   repository ecosystem, which is key for
>   deployment, management and operations
>   scenarios. And last, but not least was
>   performance.
>
> Earlier in his talk, Kenny cited
>   intriguing improvements, including 10x
>   to 100x performance improvements and
>   persisted workflows becoming
>   essentially "free" with WF 4.0. In our
>   more one-on-one discussion after his
>   talk, he used the analogy of swinging
>   at a baseball with a wooden baseball
>   bat. While the wooden baseball bat is
>   effective, it feels a bit heavy, if
>   not clunky at times. When you pick up
>   an aluminum baseball bat, it is
>   markedly lighter, and feels
>   significantly more aerodynamic. WF 3.0
>   and 3.5 work, but WF 4 is a new and
>   improved aluminum baseball bat.

Comment: Thanks, I'm definitely looking forward to PDC 2008!

Comment: Panos - any news of this, now that PDC08 is finished?

Answer (score 2):

I once did some benchmark about WF performance. It turns out that "declarative condition" is pretty slow. I believe that it is due to a lot of reflection is done in the process.